# Regex pattern numbers followed by a character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying get the Regex right for the following scenario but have some trouble. Below is the scenario.

My string looks like this:

`"The office timing (h) is from 8h to 18h."`

From the above string I need `"8h"` and `"18h"`.

So far I have done this `"[0-9]*[h]"`. But this gives me `"h"`, `"8h"` and `"18h"`.

Any ideas from experts out there?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Even this will help : `[0-9][0-9]*h` which is equivalent to `[0-9]+h`

Comment: `[0-9][0-9]*h` is not equivalent to `[0-9]+h`. As @Li0liQ noted `[0-9][0-9]*h` is equivalent to `[0-9]{1,2}h`.

Answer (score 11):

Replace `[0-9]*[h]` with `[0-9]+h`

The `+` means it must appear once or more. And there is no use in bracketing the `h`, because it stands alone.

You can also use `\d+h` for more readability (`\d` matches any digit).

Answer (score 4):

replace the * with a + (plus sign), i.e.

[0-9]+[h]

In regex speak:

* means match any number of the previous tokens (INCLUDING zero)

+ means match any number of the previous tokens (AT LEAST ONE)

Also, the square brackets around the h are redundant as you are only matching a single character.

Answer (score 3):

`*` means zero or more repetitions in Regex. Specify the corret numer of repetitions instead.

`"\b\d{1,2}h\b"`

`\d` stands for one digit.

`{1,2}` means one or two repetitions (of `\d`).

`\b` means beginning or end of word (because no letter or digit should precede or follow the pattern).

It will not find `"h"` or `"123h"` or `"18hertz"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\b\d+h\b
```