# Extract post numeric value from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i want to get post digits from "KB"(Actual data size)
for example

```
string word1="Product data 5KB per second" 
string word2="Product data is 5 KB per hour"
```

i want to extract 5 from the above words if i pass KB

Comment: You can have many KB in one string?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Amit i have only 1 KB in my string

Comment: Why can you not find the text between "Product data is " and "KB"?

Comment: @Amit: first example says _"Product data "_ not _"Product data is "_

Comment: But the thing is "Product data is "  string is not constant ,its changing 
the fixed part is  KB only

Comment: @paulF ,The Exact thing is 5KB and 5 KB(space between them) .In both case i need 5 as result

Comment: One basic answer - not the best - would be to split on KB, trim first string & extract the trailing numeric characters. Really you should try some things yourself. Regex would be a help here.

Comment: What have you tried? See for example [Regex pattern numbers followed by a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786088/regex-pattern-numbers-followed-by-a-character), found by searching the web for "c# find number followed by letter in string".

Answer (score 2):

This Regex should work

```
var word2Size = Regex.Match(word2, @"\d+(?=\s?KB)").Value;
```

or for floating point numbers

```
var word2Size = Regex.Match(word2, @"\d+\.?\d+(?=\s?KB)").Value;
```

it should return a numeric value immediately preceding optional whitespace followed by KB

You could generate a regex string for different suffix with :

```
string regexString = String.Format(@"\d+\.?\d+(?=\s?{0})", mySuffix);
var word2Size = Regex.Match(word2, regexString).Value;
```

Comment: That's the one :D, was trying a lookahead before the pattern though for the floating point the second digit group should be as optional as the "." since + is one or many `\d+\.?\d*`

Comment: Thanks Bro,Its work

Comment: Glad to be of help - you should mark the answer as correct for anyone with similar question